# how we can implement "not like" with $not in mongodb with multiline search

Tags: php, json, regex, mongodb

below query works fine to word within whole sentence.

```
 db.candidate.find( {
 $and : [
 { permanent_address: { $not:  /kendriya/ } } ,
 { current_address: { $not:  /India/ } } 
 ]
 }
```

)

but problem is that
i have an below array

```
 Array 
 (
   [$and] => Array
    (
        [0] => Array
            (
                [permanent_address] => Array
                    (
                        [$not] => /kendriya/
                    )

            )
        [1] => Array
            (
                [current_address] => Array
                    (
                        [$not] => /India/
                    )

            )
            )
            )
```

when i encode it to pass it to mongo db to get result then json will change 
 as

```
$and : 
 [
 { permanent_address: { $not: "/kendriya/" } } ,
 { current_address: { $not:  "/India/" } } 
 ]
 }
 ]
```

generate json string will quoted that why result not getting so 
how we can solve this problem.

Answer (score 2):

Create mongodb regex variables and then pass those variables in query.

```
$paddress = new MongoRegex("/kendriya/");
$caddress = new MongoRegex("/India/");

Array 
 (
   [$and] => Array
    (
        [0] => Array
            (
                [permanent_address] => Array
                    (
                        [$not] => $paddress
                    )

            )
        [1] => Array
            (
                [current_address] => Array
                    (
                        [$not] => $caddress
                    )

            )
            )
            )
```

Or you can use this to create regex

$paddress = new MongoDB\BSON\Regex ('/kendriya/');

as mentioned here http://php.net/manual/en/class.mongodb-bson-regex.php

Comment: Yes mongodb $regex function don't work with $not, that's why you need to use language regex capabilities to generate regular expression object.

Is MongoRegex not working?

Comment: hi...please give example of use language regex to solve  this problem

Comment: please give example to solve this problem without use of mongoregex